# Meteor make user defined HTML or SVG reactive

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

In my multi-user meteor application design I want to enable users to be able to create and store their own reactive dashboards to visualize data that they own within the applications database. For example, a user may have an object in the database representing the real-time disk usage of a processor. I want them to be able to submit/store html say to represent a dynamic dial as their dashboard. Another user may have their own weather station and want a dashboard with a last 24 hours thermometer and pressure trend. When they call up one of their stored dashboards it is rendered and would update as their data changes.

Can anyone point to example code or explain how to accomplish this? Or, authoritatively explain why it cannot be done in the framework. I have come across various dynamic API's but nothing that fits the bill. I.e. UI.renderWithData and Meteor._def_template.

Answer (score 0):

The following topic was very similar to my questions and it got me a good start and I figured it out and posted and answer there.

[How to make meteor evaluate user defined template text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23415182/how-to-make-meteor-evaluate-spacebars-from-a-dynamically-generated-template-html)